# How to efficiently compute the sum of squares of each of row of a sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix M and I want to compute the sum of the squares of the entries for each row. So for a small matrix I could write (in R):

`x <- diag(M %*% t(M))`

However, my matrix is a sparse matrix with about 10 million rows and 100 columns and doing the above first computes the entire 10 million by 10 million matrix and then extracts the diagonal from it and hence is very inefficient.

What would be a good way to do this with matrix operations without computing unneeded values?

Comment: With 10 million rows, the question is rather how are you loading this data into R, and why do you insist on doing a matrix operation, when you could simply do a simple operation on a row-by-row basis?

Comment: @MrGumble R has support for sparse matrices, so loading a matrix that size into R is not hard. Doing a for loop over 10 million rows doesn't seem efficient either, as the looping will be done in R whereas the matrix operations are translated to C which is much faster.

Comment: This might be naive considering no one suggested it yet but how about `rowSums(M^2)`? Another option would be to use parallel processing with `apply()`.

Comment: You don't need to loop *per row*, by since your rows are independent for this operation, you can pull in chunks of your data and use the approach suggested by Neeraj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this by using apply function. For example, `Mat` is your relevant matrix, then

```
apply(Mat, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(x^2))
```

Comment: do you know if that properly/efficiently handles the sparse matrix case?

Answer (score 1):

The `apply()` function does not work for large data. I think it simply transforms each row to a vector with lots of 0s..

You can use `Matrix::rowSums(M ** 2)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The simple `rowSums(M**2)` shoud be the most effective for the purpose.